# The div that holds my content is overlapping the navbar and disappearing when resizing Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, overlapping

The content (.intro-header) is overlapping the navbar when resizing. I already add margin-bottom to the id=container (where the navbar is) but this not seem to work.

The ideal thing would be too that when i click in the toggle menu, the dropdown menu wouldn't over lap the content as well.

My content should be centered i use transform: translate, position fixed.
here's my code`

```css
html body {
 height: 100%;
 
}


hr {
  border: none;
  background-color: #202A25;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: 0em;
}


#container {
 margin-bottom:100px;
}

.intro-header {

 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;

 /* Center always */
 transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}

.line2 {
 position: relative;
 top: 10px;
 height: 3px;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Mirador';
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
}

.container {
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--css style-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<hr>
  <div id="container">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block" href="#"><img src=""></a>
    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-text d-none-xs-block d d-sm-block d-md-none d-lg-none d-xl-none" href="#">R a n d o m o o d</a>

    
    <!--button when collapsed-->
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
     <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
     </ul> 
    </div> 
    
   </nav>
   
  </div>
  <div class="intro-header">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <h1>Need a Graphic Designer?</h1>
       <!--line-->
       <hr class="line2" align="center" width="50%">
      </div> 
      
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

`

Comment: What div? Can you please clarify the question?

Comment: the content (div class="intro-header")